How to receive callback from telegram bot
public class TelegramBotController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TelegramBotClient _botClient;
    private const string BotToken = "MyToken";

    public TelegramBotController()
    {
        _botClient = new TelegramBotClient(BotToken);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Telegram.Bot.Types.Update update)
    {
        await _botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: myUserId, "Hello guys");

        return Ok();
    }
}

This is my code to receive a callback from my bot telegram, I also use postman to call setwebhook successfully.
When I send text to my telegram bot, it didn't receive the callback.
I'm following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Er2kaKxaBg
I tried to search and use chatgpt for help but it is not working. My expectation is to receive callback from telegram and send it back the messages

To receive callbacks you need to setup a webhook URL for Telegram to call you back when there is a change in status.
Refer the below code :
public class TelegramBotController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TelegramBotClient _botClient;
    private const string BotToken = "YourBotToken";

    public TelegramBotController()
    {
        _botClient = new TelegramBotClient(BotToken);
    }

    [HttpPost("/webhook")] // Set up your webhook URL here
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Update update)
    {
        if (update == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        
        if (update.Message != null)
        {
            
            await HandleIncomingMessage(update.Message); // For incoming messages
        }
        else if (update.CallbackQuery != null)
        {
            
            await HandleIncomingCallbackQuery(update.CallbackQuery); // For incoming callback queries
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    private async Task HandleIncomingMessage(Message message)
    {
        
        await _botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: message.Chat.Id, text: "Hello guys"); // Your message handling logic here
    }

    private async Task HandleIncomingCallbackQuery(CallbackQuery callbackQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Call back query Incomming");
    }
}

